# kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iOS stops at 4.2

Tags: ios

Does anyone know why the `kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_X_X` constants were not updated to include 4.3 and 5.0? It's not a big deal to add them manually, but just wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question - it doesn't get much love, the documentation only has it going up to iOS 2.2, even though in the header itself it runs to 4.2.

What are you using it for? Apple's preferred approach (or at least, the approach in their sample code) is to use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` to determine OS version.

The only thing I can suggest is if it's of importance to you you should file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Yeah. I was more hoping to avoid having to do a string comparison on system version.